# git rebase -i, удалить pick коммита или использовать fixup, разница?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase

Пример. Запустили интерактивный rebase, получаем:

```
pick f7f3f6d Oldest commit message
pick 310154e Middle commit message
pick a5f4a0d Newest commit message
```

Мы хотим удалить средний коммит (310154e).

*Можно сделать так:*

```
pick f7f3f6d Oldest commit message
pick a5f4a0d Newest commit message
```

Удаление pick коммита удаляет его из истории. Но куда деваются произведенные им изменения? Мержаться к старшему коммиту? Или к младшему?

*Или можно использовать другой вариант:*

```
pick f7f3f6d Oldest commit message
fixup 310154e Middle commit message
pick a5f4a0d Newest commit message
```

В этом случае fixup мержит изменения среднего коммита (310154e) с изменениями из старшего (f7f3f6d) и удаляет оба коммита из истории, создавая новый коммит с суммарными изменениями и сообщением из старшего (f7f3f6d).

*Как работает удаление pick коммита и в чем разница между этими способами удаления коммитов из истории?*

Comment: Вы можете сделать тестовый репозиторий и в нём проверить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, так и сделаю если долго не будет ответа, но хотелось-бы увидеть где эта разница обозначена в официальной документации, так как эксперементальные попытки найти разницу могут показать не полную картину

Comment: Экспериментальные попытки  покажут вам объективную реальность. Она нередко отличается от той реальности, которая описана в документации, и тем более от той, которая появляется в голове разработчика, который прочитал документацию.

Comment: @NickVolynkin согласен, эксперименты нужны и важны, но если есть документация, знакомство с ней перед началом экспериментов может сократить много времени и раскрыть тонкие детали для редких случаев, попытка нащупать которые экспериментальным путем была бы подобна брутфорсу пароля. Вот у физиков нет документации от нашей объективной реальности, и сколько лет уже экспериментально доказать не могут, волны вокруг нас или частицы или что вообще :-)

Comment: чуть позже накидаю тестовый репозиторий, чтобы проверить разные возможные случаи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Удаление pick коммита удаляет его из истории. Но куда деваются произведенные им изменения?

по-простому говоря — удаляются.

более точно: соответствующие объекты (*деревья* — *tree* и *блобы* — *blob*), включённые в удаляемые *commit*-ы (и сами *commit*-ы), конечно, остаются в репозитории, но, если удаляемые *commit*-ы не были включены в другую цепочку *commit*-ов (с помощью тегов или других веток), все они (*коммиты*, *деревья*, *блобы*) становятся «бесхозными» и будут удалены при очередной «сборке мусора».

**дополнение**

таким образом, основная разница между удалением строки и заменой действия `pick` на `fuxup` состоит в том, что в первом случае изменения, закреплённые этим *commit*-ом, **удаляются**, а во втором они (изменения) **включаются** в дргуой *commit*.

Comment: Да, этот механизм я понимаю, при rebase, все коммиты наследуемые от того коммита с которого мы начали rebase будут удалены (но останутся в репозитории в состоянии dangling commits), а вместо них будут созданы новые. Тоже происходит при использовании commit --amend, старый коммит уходит в состояние dangling и создается новый.

Comment: Но куда приписываются изменения при удалении pick commit во время rebase, родителю этого коммита, как при fixup, или "никуда" (то есть разницу станет видно в диффах родителя удаленного коммита и его наследников, которые раньше ссылались на удаленный коммит)?

Comment: при удалении строки во время `git rebase -i ...` изменения «уйдут в никуда».

Comment: Тогда, возможно это и есть основная разница между удалением pick и fixup. fixup, как и squash, добавляет изменения из удаляемого коммита его родителю, а удаление pick этого не делает, и изменения из удаленного коммита оказываются в диффах его бывших наследников.

Comment: *Тогда, возможно это и есть основная разница между удалением pick и fixup* ­— да, это и есть основная разница. я посчитал это очевидным и не стал писать об этом в ответе. сейчас допишу.

Comment: @Dima, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Если что, на английской версии есть подобный вопрос без ответа, можно добавить это и туда: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745114/differences-between-fixup-and-removing-a-commit-in-git-rebase

Comment: @Dima, вижу по вашей ссылке и ответ.

Comment: Ответ есть, но он не содержит нужной информации и не принят правильным (мне кажется, там вообще что-то странное написано), так что я сам изложил бы там информацию отсюда, но так как это ваш ответ, то на случай если вы захотите ответить там сами, я дал ссылку